# Do exists a mathematical operation that reflects a matrix along an axis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Frequently I need to mirror a matrix along an horizontal or vertical axis, in Excel.

I ask if there is a matrix operation that does it. For example, a product with some rotation matrix.

For example:

```
1 0 3
0 0 0
7 0 8
```

Mirrored along a vertical axis:

```
3 0 1
0 0 0
8 0 7
```

Or along an horizontal axis

```
7 0 8
0 0 0
1 0 3
```

I'm not particularly asking about Excel, although if it is easier to implement in Excel, or with non rectangular matrices, it would be a plus.

Since a matrix can rotate vectors, and reflections are rotations on higher dimensions (I don't know how), I hope there is an easy matrix product capable of doing it.

Comment: [Householder transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Householder_transformation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplication on the right by a permutation matrix permutes the columns, so, for example,

```
a b   0 1     b a
    x      =   
c d   1 0     d c
```

Multiplication on the left permutes rows.

The matrix

```
0 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 0
```

will manage the reflections you need.

Comment: The answer would be complete if you include rotation along an horizontal axis

Comment: @Lewec Multiplication on the left permutes the rows.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the square matrix with $1$'s along the anti-diagonal. Right multiply for the vertical axis and left multiply for the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a matrix can be viewed as a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, and because you are permuting indices there is a linear map $L: \mathbb{R}^{n^2} \to \mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ which does this. As a matrix it will be $n^2 \times n^2.$ Note that if you want to swap columns and rows, then

$$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} A$$

Will swap the first two rows of $A$, and
$$A \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
will swap the first two columns of $A$ (and similar matrices for swapping the other row/columns with each other).

However, perhaps what you want is
$$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
a_4 & a_5 & a_6 \\ a_7 & a_8 & a_9 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a_2 & a_3 & a_6 \\
a_1 & a_5 & a_9 \\ a_4 & a_7 & a_8 \end{pmatrix} $$
when you say 'rotation?